# Get channel table file from remote server

Tags: java, ftp, ibm-mq

I'm trying to set ccdturl with the ccdt file which located in a remote server. I tried to set ccdt url using ftp but it does not work out. Does anyone know what is the correct way to set url for ccdt file in remote server?
Thanks!

I tried:

```
String channelTablePath = "ftp://user@host:/path-to-ccdt-file";
Url url = new URL(channelTablePath );
connectionFactory.setCCDTURL(url);
```

The error that I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jms.JMSException: JMSWMQ2020: Failed to connect                                                                                              to queue manager '*QQ' with connection mode 'Client' and supplied CCDT URL 'ftp://user@host:/path/ccdt.tab',                                                                                              see linked exception for more information.
JMS Error code: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2278' ('MQRC_CLIENT_CONN_ERROR').
EXPLANATION:
The filesystem returned error code 'java.net.ConnectException[Connection timed
out]' for file 'ftp://user@host:/path/ccdt.tab'.
ACTION:
Record the name of the file 'ftp://user@host:/path/ccdt.tab'
and tell the systems administrator, who should ensure that file 'ftp://user@host:/path/ccdt.tab'
is correct and available.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary:

You should not have a colon (`:`) after the host in the URL.  You should specify a password value in the URL if required.  You also need to specify the name of the ccdt file.  References to the IBM Knowlege center at at the end of this answer.

Try the following value instead:

```
String channelTablePath = "ftp://user:pass@host/path-to-ccdt-file/AMQCLCHL.TAB";
```

---

The IBM MQ v9 Knowledge center page "[Using a client channel definition table with IBM MQ classes for JMS](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032510_.htm)" states:

> As another example, suppose the file ccdt2.tab contains a client
>   channel definition table and is stored on a system that is different
>   from the one on which the application is running. If the file can be
>   accessed using the FTP protocol, the application can set the CCDTURL
>   property in the following way:
>
> ```
> java.net.URL chanTab2 = new URL("ftp://ftp.server/admdata/ccdt2.tab");
> factory.setCCDTURL(chanTab2);
> ```

---

The IBM MQ v9 Knowledge center page "[Web addressable access to the client channel definition table](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.con.doc/q016735_.htm)" shows an example of a FTP URL with username and password:

> Authenticated connections
>
> ```
> export MQCHLLIB=ftp://myuser:password@myhost.sample.com/var/mqm/qmgrs/QMGR/@ipcc
> export MQCHLLIB=http://myuser:password@myhost.sample.com/var/mqm/qmgrs/QMGR/@ipcc
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **Note**
>
> If you want to use authenticated connections you must, **as with JMS, provide the user name and password encoded in the URL**.

Comment: Hi, so it is required that I must add in the encoded password in the url if i want to get the channel table from remote host? Is there a way that i dont need to add in the password? thx

Comment: If the ftp server requires a password for the user specified you would need to specify a password, the JMS libraries do not have any ability to prompt for this.  You could always do something like: 1. setup a passwordless user on your ftp server.  2. setup anonymous ftp. 3. put it on a http server.

Comment: If you are worried about storing the password, then have your program prompt for the password and use that in your URL string.  If it is a automated program you could place it in a config file that is locked down to only be readable by the application user.

Comment: @RLe no problem.  Could you provide more detail of what you mean by "encrypted pass".  JMS classes for MQ should be just looking for the plain text password.  Interested to know of there is some feature that I am not aware of that allows you to provide a encrypted password?

Comment: hi i have internal software use to encrypted/encode password as a string for transfer server.