# Using a Connection Name List in a JMS Load Balanced Environment

Tags: ibm-mq, spring-jms

Our JMS infrastructure is load balanced. As a result of this, I am attempting to use a connectionNameList when configuring the connection factory. The idea here is that any JMS message that arrives on either of the primary or secondary queue manager will get picked up and processed. However, it only appears that messages are being picked up by the primary.

Here is my listener annotation:

```
@JmsListener(destination = "${request-queue}", containerFactory = "DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
public void onMessage(Message msg) {
    System.out.println(msg.toString());
}
```

Here is the JMS listener container factory:

```
@Bean(name = "DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory")
public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory createJmsListenerContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

    factory.setConnectionFactory(buildConnectionFactory());
    factory.setConcurrency(numberOfListeners);
    factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    factory.setSessionTransacted(false);
    factory.setErrorHandler(queueErrorHandler);
    factory.setBackOff(getBackOffStrategy());

    return factory;
}
```

And here is the connection factory:

```
@Bean(name = "MQConnectionFactory")
public ConnectionFactory buildConnectionFactory() {

    try {
        MQConnectionFactory mqcf = new MQConnectionFactory();
        mqcf.setConnectionNameList(mq1.daluga.com(2171),mq2.daluga.com(2171));
        mqcf.setChannel(channel);
        mqcf.setTransportType(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
        return mqcf;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(message, e);
    }
}
```

I suspect something in my configuration is just not right. Is there anything obvious that folks see that might cause messages not to be picked up from the secondary queue manager?

Thanks!

Comment: The connections listed in the setConnectionNameList will be tried from left to right.  You will only connect to the second conname if the first conname is unavailable.  To do what you are looking at you can look at IBM MQ CCDT or putting a hardware load balancer (ex: F5 LTM) in front of your MQ servers.

Comment: Related to a CCDT, you can create a CCDT with channels to each queue manager (note the channel names must be different on each queue manager) the `QMNAME` will be the same on all of them and then you reference it in your program as `*QMNAME` which tells it that it is a group of channels to look up.  In the CCDT you can set it up with equal weighting or you can set things so some have higher priority.

Comment: two other answers that provide some CCDT info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48588673/get-channel-table-file-from-remote-server/48591998#48591998
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969323/connecting-to-ibm-mq-using-ccdt-file-in-jms/45971106#45971106

Comment: Thanks, @JoshMc. Thanks for helping me understand this. I was under the impression that this was implemented for load balancing when I think the reason for the connection name list is really just failover.

Comment: Dan I can write up a quick answer with the info from the comments above if you would accept it and feel it may be helpful to others.